# Как преобразовать многомерный php массив в JSON без ключей

Tags: php, массивы, json

Есть многомерный php массив, вся вложенность в нем динамическая ( в моем случае это корзина ):

```
$array = array(
'items' => array(array
   '1' => array(
      'name' => 'Блюдо 1',
      'price' => '100',
      'modifiers' => array(array(
         'modifier_name' => 'Модификатор 1.1',
         'modifier_price' => '150',
      ),),
    ),

   '2' => array(
      'name' => 'Блюдо 2',
      'price' => '200',
      'modifiers' => array(array(
         '1' => array(
            'modifier_name' => 'Модификатор 2.1',
            'modifier_price' => '250',
         ),

         '2' => array(
            'modifier_name' => 'Модификатор 2.2',
            'modifier_price' => '260',
         ),
     ),),
   ),
),),
);
```

Из этого массива нужно получить вот такой JSON:

```
{

"items": [
 {
   "name": "Блюдо 1",
   "price": "100",
   "modifiers": [
     {
       "modifier_name": "Модификатор 1.1",
       "modifier_price": "150",
     }
   ]
 },

 {
   "name": "Блюдо 2",
   "price": "200",
   "modifiers": [
     {
       "modifier_name": "Модификатор 2.1",
       "modifier_price": "250",
     },

     {
       'modifier_name' => 'Модификатор 2.2',
       'modifier_price' => '260',
     }
   ]
 }
],

}
```

Как решить данную задачу с условием того, что вложенность и данные динамические? Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: "такой" джейсон получить невозможно. нужно привести **реальный** пример.

Comment: но в целом я бы оставил как есть. если 1 и 2 - это идентификаторы ингедиентов, то лучше их оставить в корзине

Comment: @Bloom не стоит постить не относящиеся к вопросу ссылки на левые сайты

Comment: Данный json требует api сторонней программы, я бы с радостью оставил все как есть

Comment: это НЕ джейсон. как минимум должны быть скобки по краям. А преобразовать просто - array_values в цикле

Comment: Я исправил, может так будет понятнее

Answer (score -1):

Вот вам кусок формирования вывода, надеюсь он вам поможет разобраться как получиться желаемый результат

```js
$temp = ['items' => [
  (object)[
    'name' => 'Блюдо 1',
    'price' => '100',
    'modifiers' => [
      (object)[
        'modifier_name' => 'Модификатор 1.1',
        'modifier_price' => '150'
      ]
    ]
  ]
]];
print_r(json_encode($temp));
exit;
```

Comment: нет, не поможет